# why <script>alert(/XSS/)</script> pop up /XSS/

Tags: javascript

```
<script>alert(/XSS/)</script>
```

As stated in the title. Confused for a long time.I am learning javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/.../` syntax creates a `RegExp` object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Therefore, `/XSS/` is an instance of `RegExp`. When you pass it to `alert(...)`, it calls the `.toString()` method, which happens to be the string `"/XSS/"`